# Python script ending with Process signal 11: SIGSEGV

Tags: python, debugging, pyqt, segmentation-fault

From some months I have the following problem. When I run some python scripts (note, not only one script, but also not all of them), after few seconds they crash with the following error

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

The most interesting thing is that **this never happens if I run the same scripts in the PyCharm debugger**.

The setting of the PyCharm Debugger is `PyQt = Auto` (but changing this setting the scripts will crash with the same error).
My `.bashrc` file contains

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/samuele/Projects/Coppeliasim
```

However, adding or removing this line seems irrelevant to this problem.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to provide a minimal example. I am keen to update this question with all the information needed.

More info:

1. I use `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`
2. I use `Python 3.6` with `Anaconda` environment
3. Seems that the script crashes consistently (i.e., some script always crashes, some always run correctly)
4. Interestingly, if a script immediately opens a `matplotlib` windows, it will crash only after I close the window
5. It seems to me that the script **not crashing** are the one that import [RLBench](http://alendar.google.com/calendar), which uses [CoppeliaSim](https://www.coppeliarobotics.com/).
6. `CoppeliaSim` requires the following line in the `.bashrc`

```sh
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so
export COPPELIASIM_ROOT=/home/samuele/Projects/Coppeliasim
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=$COPPELIASIM_ROOT
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/samuele/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$COPPELIASIM_ROOT
```

7. It seems to me that the problem began after the installation of Coppelia, but I have no certainty
8. the version I have currently installed on my virtual environment are

```
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h05f1152_2  
pyqt5                     5.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-sip                 12.8.0                   pypi_0    pypi
```

### GDB

The `run script.py` command in `gdb` output

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff2c71700 (LWP 17543)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff2470700 (LWP 17544)]
...
[Thread 0x7fffbe45c700 (LWP 17569) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffbbc5b700 (LWP 17568) exited]
Thread 1 "python" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7de1b18 in elf_machine_rela (skip_ifunc=0, 
    reloc_addr_arg=0x7fff75386fa8, version=0x18, sym=0x7fff75116728, 
    reloc=0x7fff751170e8, map=0x555556aea650)
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h:308
308 ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h: No such file or directory.
```

The `backtrace` command output

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7de1b18 in elf_machine_rela (skip_ifunc=0, reloc_addr_arg=0x7fff75386fa8, version=0x18, sym=0x7fff75116728, reloc=0x7fff751170e8, map=0x555556ae9c90) at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h:308
#1  elf_dynamic_do_Rela (skip_ifunc=0, lazy=<optimized out>, nrelative=<optimized out>, relsize=<optimized out>, reladdr=<optimized out>, map=0x555556ae9c90) at do-rel.h:137
#2  _dl_relocate_object (scope=<optimized out>, reloc_mode=reloc_mode@entry=0, consider_profiling=<optimized out>, consider_profiling@entry=0) at dl-reloc.c:258
#3  0x00007ffff7dea10d in dl_open_worker (a=a@entry=0x7fffffff87b0) at dl-open.c:382
#4  0x00007ffff769751f in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=0x7fffffff8790, operate=0x7ffff7de9e10 <dl_open_worker>, args=0x7fffffff87b0) at dl-error-skeleton.c:196
#5  0x00007ffff7de981a in _dl_open (file=0x7fff78575c50 "libc.so.6", mode=-2147483642, caller_dlopen=0x7fffb8efc8d9 <py_dl_open+137>, nsid=<optimized out>, argc=2, argv=<optimized out>, 
    env=0x55555593c210) at dl-open.c:605
#6  0x00007ffff732cf96 in dlopen_doit (a=a@entry=0x7fffffff89e0) at dlopen.c:66
#7  0x00007ffff769751f in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7fffffff8980, operate=0x7ffff732cf40 <dlopen_doit>, args=0x7fffffff89e0) at dl-error-skeleton.c:196
#8  0x00007ffff76975af in __GI__dl_catch_error (objname=0x5555558a7270, errstring=0x5555558a7278, mallocedp=0x5555558a7268, operate=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at dl-error-skeleton.c:215
#9  0x00007ffff732d745 in _dlerror_run (operate=operate@entry=0x7ffff732cf40 <dlopen_doit>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffff89e0) at dlerror.c:162
#10 0x00007ffff732d051 in __dlopen (file=<optimized out>, mode=<optimized out>) at dlopen.c:87
#11 0x00007fffb8efc8d9 in py_dl_open () at /usr/local/src/conda/python-3.6.9/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c:1377
#12 0x0000555555665b91 in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/methodobject.c:234
#13 0x00005555556edabc in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4851
#14 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#15 0x00005555556e729e in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#16 0x00005555556e8598 in _PyFunction_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5084
#17 0x000055555566601f in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2310
#18 0x000055555566aaa3 in _PyObject_Call_Prepend () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2373
#19 0x0000555555665a5e in PyObject_Call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2261
#20 0x00005555556be9eb in slot_tp_init () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/typeobject.c:6420
#21 0x00005555556eddf7 in type_call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/typeobject.c:915
#22 0x0000555555665e3b in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2331
#23 0x00005555556e818a in _PyObject_FastCallKeywords () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2496
#24 0x00005555556edc0e in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4875
#25 0x000055555571151c in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3351
#26 0x00005555556e7c5b in _PyFunction_FastCall (globals=<optimized out>, nargs=1, args=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4933
#27 fast_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4968
#28 0x00005555556edb95 in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4872
#29 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#30 0x00005555556e729e in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#31 0x00005555556e7ed6 in fast_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4992
#32 0x00005555556edb95 in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4872
#33 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#34 0x00005555556e7c5b in _PyFunction_FastCall (globals=<optimized out>, nargs=1, args=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4933
#35 fast_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4968
#36 0x00005555556edb95 in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4872
#37 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#38 0x00005555556e6e66 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#39 0x00005555556e8598 in _PyFunction_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5084
#40 0x000055555566601f in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2310
#41 0x000055555566aaa3 in _PyObject_Call_Prepend () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2373
#42 0x0000555555665a5e in PyObject_Call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2261
#43 0x00005555556be9eb in slot_tp_init () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/typeobject.c:6420
#44 0x00005555556eddf7 in type_call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/typeobject.c:915
#45 0x0000555555665e3b in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2331
#46 0x00005555556e818a in _PyObject_FastCallKeywords () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2496
#47 0x00005555556edc0e in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4875
#48 0x000055555571151c in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3351
#49 0x00005555556e7c5b in _PyFunction_FastCall (globals=<optimized out>, nargs=1, args=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4933
#50 fast_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4968
#51 0x00005555556edb95 in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4872
#52 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#53 0x00005555556e6e66 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#54 0x00005555556e8598 in _PyFunction_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5084
#55 0x000055555566601f in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2310
#56 0x000055555566aaa3 in _PyObject_Call_Prepend () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2373
#57 0x0000555555665a5e in PyObject_Call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2261
#58 0x00005555556be9eb in slot_tp_init () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/typeobject.c:6420
#59 0x00005555556eddf7 in type_call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/typeobject.c:915
#60 0x0000555555665e3b in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2331
#61 0x00005555556e818a in _PyObject_FastCallKeywords () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2496
#62 0x00005555556edc0e in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4875
#63 0x000055555571151c in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3351
#64 0x00005555556e6e66 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#65 0x00005555556e7ed6 in fast_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4992
#66 0x00005555556edb95 in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4872
#67 0x000055555571151c in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3351
#68 0x00005555556e6e66 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#69 0x00005555556e7e73 in fast_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4992
#70 0x00005555556edb95 in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4872
#71 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#72 0x00005555556e7c5b in _PyFunction_FastCall (globals=<optimized out>, nargs=2, args=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4933
#73 fast_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4968
#74 0x00005555556edb95 in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4872
#75 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#76 0x00005555556e729e in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#77 0x00005555556e7ed6 in fast_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4992
#78 0x00005555556edb95 in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4872
#79 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#80 0x00005555556e7c5b in _PyFunction_FastCall (globals=<optimized out>, nargs=2, args=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4933
#81 fast_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4968
#82 0x00005555556edb95 in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4872
#83 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#84 0x00005555556e7c5b in _PyFunction_FastCall (globals=<optimized out>, nargs=1, args=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4933
#85 fast_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4968
#86 0x00005555556edb95 in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4872
#87 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#88 0x00005555556e6e66 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#89 0x00005555556e8598 in _PyFunction_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5084
#90 0x000055555566601f in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2310
#91 0x000055555566aaa3 in _PyObject_Call_Prepend () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2373
#92 0x0000555555665a5e in PyObject_Call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2261
#93 0x0000555555711e37 in do_call_core (kwdict=0x7fff7823d360, callargs=0x7fffb77e2e48, func=0x7ffff7ec3048) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5120
#94 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3404
#95 0x00005555556e6e66 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#96 0x00005555556e837e in _PyFunction_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5084
#97 0x000055555566601f in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2310
#98 0x000055555566aaa3 in _PyObject_Call_Prepend () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2373
#99 0x0000555555665a5e in PyObject_Call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2261
#100 0x00005555556bf371 in slot_tp_call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/typeobject.c:6207
#101 0x0000555555665e3b in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2331
#102 0x00005555556edc0e in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4875
#103 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#104 0x00005555556e6e66 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#105 0x00005555556e8598 in _PyFunction_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5084
#106 0x000055555566601f in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2310
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#107 0x000055555566aaa3 in _PyObject_Call_Prepend () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2373
#108 0x0000555555665a5e in PyObject_Call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2261
#109 0x0000555555711e37 in do_call_core (kwdict=0x7fff7823d438, callargs=0x7ffff59073c8, func=0x7fffb8259f48) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5120
#110 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3404
#111 0x00005555556e6e66 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#112 0x00005555556e837e in _PyFunction_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5084
#113 0x000055555566601f in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2310
#114 0x000055555566aaa3 in _PyObject_Call_Prepend () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2373
#115 0x0000555555665a5e in PyObject_Call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2261
#116 0x00005555556bf371 in slot_tp_call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/typeobject.c:6207
#117 0x0000555555665e3b in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2331
#118 0x00005555556edc0e in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4875
#119 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#120 0x00005555556e6e66 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#121 0x00005555556e8598 in _PyFunction_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5084
#122 0x000055555566601f in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2310
#123 0x000055555566aaa3 in _PyObject_Call_Prepend () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2373
#124 0x0000555555665a5e in PyObject_Call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2261
#125 0x0000555555711e37 in do_call_core (kwdict=0x7fff7823d3f0, callargs=0x7ffff7f16198, func=0x7ffff7f99348) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5120
#126 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3404
#127 0x00005555556e6e66 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#128 0x00005555556e837e in _PyFunction_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5084
#129 0x000055555566601f in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2310
#130 0x000055555566aaa3 in _PyObject_Call_Prepend () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2373
#131 0x0000555555665a5e in PyObject_Call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2261
#132 0x00005555556bf371 in slot_tp_call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/typeobject.c:6207
#133 0x0000555555665e3b in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2331
#134 0x00005555556edc0e in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4875
#135 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#136 0x00005555556e7c5b in _PyFunction_FastCall (globals=<optimized out>, nargs=2, args=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4933
#137 fast_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4968
#138 0x00005555556edb95 in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4872
#139 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#140 0x00005555556e7c5b in _PyFunction_FastCall (globals=<optimized out>, nargs=1, args=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4933
#141 fast_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4968
#142 0x00005555556edb95 in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4872
#143 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#144 0x00005555556e7401 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#145 0x00005555556e837e in _PyFunction_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:5084
#146 0x000055555566601f in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2310
#147 0x000055555566aaa3 in _PyObject_Call_Prepend () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2373
#148 0x0000555555665a5e in PyObject_Call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2261
#149 0x00005555556be9eb in slot_tp_init () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/typeobject.c:6420
#150 0x00005555556eddf7 in type_call () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/typeobject.c:915
#151 0x0000555555665e3b in _PyObject_FastCallDict () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Objects/abstract.c:2331
#152 0x00005555556edc0e in call_function () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4875
#153 0x000055555571075a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:3335
#154 0x00005555556e89b9 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (qualname=0x0, name=<optimized out>, closure=0x0, kwdefs=0x0, defcount=0, defs=0x0, kwstep=2, kwcount=<optimized out>, kwargs=0x0, kwnames=0x0, 
    argcount=0, args=0x0, locals=0x7ffff7f5c2d0, globals=0x7ffff7f5c2d0, _co=0x7ffff595e810) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4166
#155 PyEval_EvalCodeEx () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:4187
#156 0x00005555556e975c in PyEval_EvalCode (co=co@entry=0x7ffff595e810, globals=globals@entry=0x7ffff7f5c2d0, locals=locals@entry=0x7ffff7f5c2d0)
    at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/ceval.c:731
#157 0x0000555555769744 in run_mod () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/pythonrun.c:1025
#158 0x0000555555769b41 in PyRun_FileExFlags () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/pythonrun.c:978
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#159 0x0000555555769d43 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/pythonrun.c:419
#160 0x0000555555769e4d in PyRun_AnyFileExFlags () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Python/pythonrun.c:81
#161 0x000055555576d833 in run_file (p_cf=0x7fffffffd5fc, filename=0x5555558aa1e0 L"test_pca.py", fp=0x55555593e6c0) at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Modules/main.c:340
#162 Py_Main () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Modules/main.c:811
#163 0x000055555563788e in main () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1564510748219/work/Programs/python.c:69
#164 0x00007ffff7551b97 in __libc_start_main (main=0x5555556377a0 <main>, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffd808, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffd7f8)
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
#165 0x0000555555717160 in _start () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/elf/start.S:103
```

Comment: Without an example is really hard to understand what's going on, but you should provide more information: Is it *always* reproducible (the same script(s) *always* crash)? If not, can you find and provide the most simple cases for which this happens *and* it doesn't? What OS are you on? What version of Python and PyQt? How did you install them? Was it a previously working setup, or did you just install/upgrade it?

Comment: @musicamante thanks! I upgraded my answer.

Comment: PyCharm is not going to help with a SEGV. You need to use gdb/lldb to figure this out. See this for more information: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I updated with the traceback of gdb! Thanks for your useful answer!

Comment: That helps! The error is occurring when the ctypes module is being used to access one of the dynamically loaded libraries. I would double check that the libraries you are trying to use are version compatible with the version of the python modules you are using,

Comment: In fact, looking closer, it is trying to dynamically link libc.so.6 - which a different version of which is probably already linked into Python. So, I believe it is a definite version mismatch. One of your libraries is built against a different version of libc than Python and the other libraries are.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I resolved the problem by building a new Conda environment. I did not further investigate the cause.